# How to view between values in dataframe pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame is

Input

```
     Index  Fruit   Price
0   Apple   55
1   Orange  98
62  Mango   141
55  Guva    184
5   Lemon   65
7   Tomato  65
8   Cabbage 65
30  Cucumber    65
31  Apple   65
35  Orange  45
9   Mango   78
22  Guva    66
11  Lemon   74
36  Tomato  57
14  Cabbage 58
12  Cucumber    59
16  Apple   60
13  Orange  61
19  Mango   62
18  Guva    63
20  Lemon   64
```

In the above dataframe I want to view only values in between index 15 and 20

Expected Output

```
Index   Fruit    Price


16  Apple   60
13  Orange  61
19  Mango   62
18  Guva    63
20  Lemon   64
```

**Provided the index is not in proper order**

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[15:20]`

Comment: @jezrael df = df.loc[15:20] doesn't work my index is not in ascending order it's random. Since the data is previously sorted.

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` and `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I got the output can I write the answer?

Comment: Yes, need `iloc` like mentioned `pyd`

Comment: Why is `13  Orange  61` in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""     Index  Fruit   Price
0   Apple   55
1   Orange  98
62  Mango   141
55  Guva    184
5   Lemon   65
7   Tomato  65
8   Cabbage 65
30  Cucumber    65
31  Apple   65
35  Orange  45
9   Mango   78
22  Guva    66
11  Lemon   74
36  Tomato  57
14  Cabbage 58
12  Cucumber    59
16  Apple   60
13  Orange  61
19  Mango   62
18  Guva    63
20  Lemon   64"""), sep='\s+')
```

Locate values in the column `Index` which are within 15 and 20 (`set_index` is to put in the desired output format, but entirely optional):

```
df.loc[(df.Index >= 15) & (df.Index <= 20)].set_index('Index')
```

Output:

```
       Fruit  Price
Index              
16     Apple     60
19     Mango     62
18      Guva     63
20     Lemon     64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `df=df.iloc[15:20]`

Comment: No that's only a part of answer

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: It's df=df.iloc[14:20]

Comment: I just showed how to slice using `iloc` for your problem, changing position is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not temporarily sort by index?

```
df.sort_index()[15:20]
#       Fruit  Price
#Index              
#16     Apple     60
#18      Guva     63
#19     Mango     62
#20     Lemon     64
```